# 3rd party cookies alternative for chat plugin

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a chat plugin which in some cases is intended to work cross-domain (i.e. the app is installed on **a.com** while the plugin is used on **b.com**).
In order to authenticate users the app relies on a third-party cookie.
This poses a problem due to the decision of modern browsers to opt completely out from using 3rd party cookies for security reasons.

I want to find a viable workaround to this issue and possible alternatives to 3rd party cookies.

Comment: Normally cross domain protocols implement some form of token based authentication in the Header.   Or alternatively if your using say websockets for your chat system, just role your own authentication as a command.

Answer (score 0):

If `b.com` wants to know which user is logged on `a.com`, it should make ajax call to `a.com` including the `credentials`:

```js
fetch('https://a.com/api/v1/users/current', {mode: 'cors', credentials: 'include'})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

On `a.com` you have to create the API endpoint `/api/v1/users/current` that will send the user data in JSON for currently logged in user. For better security it should respond only if the origin is `b.com`.